# GSON parsing with Retrofit parsing Flickr JSON response

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I seem to have the following problem. I'm using retrofit to get a JSON file and parse it into java object.

The URL i'm considering is: 
        https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=2ef592bfddc86f508550184ec706a2fc&tags=gent&per_page=2&format=json

which replies with :

```
 jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":130008,"perpage":2,"total":"260016","photo":[{"id":"15817874286","owner":"36687364@N07","secret":"e480e6fe0c","server":"7475","farm":8,"title":"3D visualisatie","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"15817785516","owner":"36687364@N07","secret":"132f12dff1","server":"7496","farm":8,"title":"schetsontwerp","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})
```

I believe the problem lies in the jsonFlickrApi in front of the response.

When executing the following code:

```
    @GET("/rest/")
void getPhotos(@Query("method") String method,@Query("api_key") String apiKey,@Query("tags") String tags,@Query("per_page")String perPage,@Query("format") String format, Callback<FlickrResult> data);
```

and

```
flickerRestAPI.getPhotos("flickr.photos.search","2ef592bfddc86f508550184ec706a2fc","gent","10","json",new Callback<FlickrResult>() {
        @Override
        public void success(FlickrResult photos, Response response) {
            Log.i(TAG, " " + photos.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Failed");
            Log.e(TAG," " +error.getUrl());
            Log.e(TAG," "+error.getMessage());

        }
    });
}
```

I get

```
 11-21 19:15:54.476  12058-12058/be.hogent.festivalproject E/MainActivity﹕ com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

The wrapper classes I'm using are:

```
public class FlickrResult {

@SerializedName("photos")
public FlickrPhotos photos;
```

}

```
public class FlickrPhotos {

public int page;
public String pages;
public int perpage;
public String total;
public ArrayList<FlickrPhoto> photo;
public String stat;}

public class FlickrPhoto {


public String id;
public String owner;
public String secret;
public String server;
public int farm;
public String title;
public int ispublic;
public int isfriend;
public int isfamily;}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply add the nojsoncallback param

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=2ef592bfddc86f508550184ec706a2fc&tags=gent&per_page=2&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

You can find it documented here

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

Comment: Thank you very much, this indeed did the trick! Been looking for it for a few hours now :)

Comment: I wish everyone would care about accepting answers the same way, they care about getting their problems solved..

Comment: Forgot to set the answer, but finished!

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `&format=json` param as well as the nojsoncallback param. Thus a sample request would be:

```
@GET("?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&format=json&nojsoncallback=1")
```